# Can any subset of $\Bbb{N}$ be an equivalence class?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

I am wondering if for any given $x \in P(\Bbb{N})- \{\emptyset\}$ we can find an equivalence relation such that it will have an equivalence class equal to $x$.

Extend of this question is whether for set $R$ of all relations in $\Bbb{N}$, the following applies: $$\bigcup_{r \in R} \Bbb{N}/_r = P(\Bbb{N}) - \{\emptyset\}$$

Comment: I don't know what the second part of your question means, but any subset can be an equivalence class.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Thanks for the answer! Is there perhaps a proof? Secondly, what is unclear in the second part?

Comment: $\{x,\mathbb N - x\}$

Comment: @LeeMosher fair enough!

Comment: It seems you are thinking that an equivalence relation needs to have a nice description.  We see the same for functions because people are used to functions and relations being specified by a description.  Lee Mosher's example is a good one partly because it shows no description is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{N}$, define an equivalence relation $n \sim m$ if and only if $m,n \in A$ or $m,n \not \in A$. It's not hard to show that this is an equivalence relation, and that $A$ is an equivalence class of that relation.